# Use Kafka offsets to calculate written messages statistics

Tags: apache-kafka

I want to get some statistics from a Kafka topic:

- total written messages
- total written messages in the last 12 hours, last hour, ...

Can I safely assume that reading the offsets for each partition in a topic  for a given timestamp (using `getOffsetsByTimes`) should give me the number of messages written in that specific time?

I can sum all the offsets for every partitions and then calculate the difference between a timestamp 1 and a timestamp 2. With these data I should be able to calculate a lot of statistics.

There are situations when these data can give me wrong results? I don't need a 100% precision, but I expect to have a reliable solution. Of course assuming that the topic is not deleted/reset.

There are other alternatives without using third party tools? (I cannot install other tools easily and I need data inside my app)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> (using getOffsetsByTimes) should give me the number of messages written in that specific time?

In *Kafka: The Definitive Guide* it mentions that the `getOffsetsByTime` is not message-based, it is *segment file* based. Meaning the time index lookup won't read into a segment file, rather it gets the first segment containing the time you are interested in. (This may have changed in newer Kafka releases since the book was released)

If you don't need accuracy, this should be fine. Do note that compacted topics don't have sequentially ordered offsets one after the other, so a simple `abs(offset@time2 - offset@time1)` won't quite work for "total existing messages in a topic".

Otherwise, plenty of JMX metrics are exposed by the brokers like bytes-in and message rates, which you can aggregate and plot over time using Grafana, for example.

Comment: Thanks @cricket_007. I cannot calculate the total number of messages inside a topic because of compaction or retention, but I should calculate the total number of messages written (also if some messages are already deleted by the log cleaner). Correct?

Comment: Non-compacted topics would be okay because there aren't messages tombstoned/cleaned between two given offsets. My comment was specifically focused on just going on offset value where gaps of offset values don't have associated messages with them, and if you tried to consume at such offset, it would just skip forward in the topic